# How do I catch and get useful information from mpi4py programs

Tags: python, mpi, slurm

I'm just learning MPI by using mpi4py and got the following error after an overnight run. The primary job didn't get to the final problem size I had specified so something terminated early. If it had been an unhandled exception, I would have expected to find the output in the log file, but maybe stderr doesn't go to that log file.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- I'm using slurm to submit jobs
- I'm using mpi4py with python3.9
- Job is a fairly simple program. Increasing problem sizes with sizes 1 through N run on each node. Then N+1 through 2N, and so on.
- I expect the problem that killed the job is running out of memory. However, I'm more interested in learning how to properly debug this (e.g. get any error output)
- I wrapped the entire program in a try/except statement and never caught an exception.

Comment: did you make sure a simple hello world program is working correctly?

Comment: Yes. In fact this one works correctly with smaller size limits.

Comment: I can get stdout from all processes, but it appears I don’t get stderr. Is there a proper MPI way to do that?